# Json array contains json objects parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsgauge

Here i need some help in json parsing

```
[{"a":0,"b":"0","c":"2A","s":"A","p":0,"Time":0},
{"a":0,"b":"0","c":"2A","s":"A","cpu":0,"Time":0},
{"a":0,"b":"0","c":"2A","s":"A","p":0,"Time":0},
{"a":0,"b":"0","c":"2A","s":"A","p":0,"Time":0},
{"a":0,"b":"0","c":"2A","s":"A","p":0,"Time":0}]
```

this is my json format. how can i iterate through the json.

```
data[0] = {"a":0,"b":"0","c":"2A","s":"A","p":0,"Time":0}; // get from iteration
```

and also get the individual item from this object
like Time=0

Comment: data[0].Time ? Or am I not understanding your question properly ...

Comment: `for(int i=0,len=data.length();i<len;i++){
  data.getJSONObject(i);
 }`

Comment: i wanna iterate json array. from first iteration i am in need of each element right? here the first json object retrived from the array, then i wanna parse each elemnt in the list.first:{"a":0,"b":"0","c":"2A","s":"A","p":0,"Time":0} second: Time=0

Comment: for (var i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
alert(i+' Element -----'+array[i].Time);

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur do you want to parse it in java or javascript!

Comment: @Anirudh exactly right

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your JSON string is called `s`, first say

```
var a = JSON.parse(s);
```

Now `a` is an array.  You iterate through it just like any other array.  If for some reason you want to   do something in particular with the `Time` property of each array element, your code will look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    doSomethingWith(a[i].Time);
}
```

Inside the loop, you can also access `a[i].a`, `a[i].b`, and so on.  Nothing is out of the ordinary here; it's all regular JavaScript.

Protip: Careful with the term "JSON object."  It isn't clear from the question you actually have a JSON string at all; you showed a regular JavaScript object.  JSON is a text format.  Once you parse the string with `JSON.parse` you are in the regular world of JavaScript, and you can use for-loops and the like to access your data.  You don't really "retrieve JSON objects out of an array". That said, there could be libraries that appear to access data out of JSON strings (similar to Xpath for XML I would think), but really, just parse the string and then you have a JavaScript array (or object).

Comment: my code is just like this 
  var data = '${Data}';
  alert(data);
   var a = JSON.parse(data);
   alert(a);
   for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       alert(a[i].Time);
   }
first alert in working and the after parsing no more alert is coming...Exactly wat is the resion

Comment: That could happen because `JSON.parse` failed.  What did you get exactly in the first alert?